# How to decode gzip string in k6

Tags: javascript, gzip, k6

I get the compressed message from webSocket and want to decompress it into k6. I am trying to use pako library via a CDN but I get the ReferenceError: window is not defined
In the case of using pako library in k6, it is a non-browser environment and does not have access to the window object.

Please tell me how can I decode and get the original JSON from the response.

Comment: `window` does not exist outside of browsers. Try maybe https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js intead of pako?